# The statement that $A \ge B$ implies $A^{-1} \le B^{-1}$ is still true for matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, quadratic-forms

**Problem:**

Suppose we have two **real, symmetric and positive definite** square matrices $A$ and $B$, i.e.,
$$A_{ij}, B_{ij}\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$A^T=A$$
$$B^T=B$$
$$x^TAx>0 \forall x$$ 
$$x^TBx>0 \forall x$$

If $A \ge B$, i.e., $A-B$ is **semi-postive definite** ($x^T(A-B)x \ge0,\,\forall x $),
then is the statement that $A^{-1} \le B^{-1}$ true, i.e. $A^{-1}-B^{-1}\ge0$ ($x^T(B^{-1}-A^{-1})x\ge0,\,\forall x $)

**Remarks:**

Obviously if $A$ and $B$ can be diagonalized simultaneously with the same similarity transformation, then the statement is true. 
What about the general case? I tried some numerical examples, it seems the statement is true. But I don't know how prove it.

I would appreciate if anyone can give a proof or point out any reference that has the solution of the above problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435831/if-a-and-b-are-positive-definite-then-is-b-1-a-1-positive-semidef

Answer (score 22):

This is a well-known fact. A simple proof : setting $y=B^{1/2}x$, we have $\|y\|^2\le y^TB^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}y$, that is $I_n\le B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$. The eigenvalues of the latter symmetric matrix are thus $\ge1$. Its inverse $B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}$ has eigenvalues $\le1$, that is $B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}\le I_n$. This gives $z^TB^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}z\le\|z\|^2$. Setting $w=B^{1/2}z$, this writes $w^TA^{-1}z\le z^TB^{-1}z$, that is $A^{-1}\le B^{-1}$.

More generally, **Loewner theory** tells you what are the operator-monotone functions. By definition, a numerical function $f:I\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ ($I$ an interval) is *monotone operator* if whenever $A,B$ are real symmetric matrices with spectra included in $I$, the inequality $A\le B$ implies $f(A)\le f(B)$. The beautiful theorem is that $f$ is operator monotone if and only if it admits a holomorphic extension to the upper half plane $\Im z>0$, with values in the upper half plane (of course this extension is unique) ; such a holomorphic function is called a *Pick function*. In particular, operator monotone functions are analytic ! For instance, if $\alpha>0$, the map $A\mapsto A^\alpha$ is monotone operator over $(0,+\infty)$ if and only if $\alpha\le1$ !!

W. F. Donoghue dedicated a full book to Loewner theorey. See also R. Bhatia's book.

Comment: Minor typo: your upper half plane has Re z not Im z

Comment: @YemonChoi. Of course ! Thank you for the point. I fix it.

Comment: For completeness of references, "R. Bhatia's book" is the book *Matrix Analysis* by Rajendra Bhatia (Springer 1997, Graduate Texts in Math. **169**), and specifically §V.4 (even more specifically, theorem V.4.7 on page 135 and proposition V.4.14 as well as the comment that follows).

Comment: A nice reference for monotone-matrix functions is the book MR0486556 by Donoghue, William F., Jr., Monotone matrix functions and analytic continuation, Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften, Band 207. Springer-Verlag,